# How to make autotype username and password in pop up?

Tags: powershell, sendkeys, autostart

I have to make a autostart script for my company that starts every morning and shows our server monitoring on a tv. The script should open up 2 seperate urls and also put it in 2 windows so you can basically just start the computer in the morning and the rest is automatic. I think its easy to open urls with just "start https://www.example.com/" but now I can't find anything on autotyping in Pop Ups especially usernames and passwords. Can anybody help me with that problem? And secondly the thing with opening it in two seperate windows, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using Selenium perhaps?  Here's a link to get you started: https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/blog/2018/12/06/powershell-selenium-and-browser-automation/